# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not behaving as expected

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a problem regarding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when launching a new activity.

Currently I have 2 applications: **application A** contains only a **service** which can start the main activity of **application B** (application B has 1 activity which is its main activity)

My problem is this: when application B is alive (its main activity is visible to the user, and it is the only activity in its task), the service gets the launching intent for application B package name (from `PackageManager`) and adds the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to it (it must do that since it is not an activity context, but a service one).

Now, when launching this intent, I expected nothing to happen since the documentation in the developers guide is as follow:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>
> When using this flag, if a task is already
>   running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity
>   will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought
>   to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.

But, for some reason another main activity of application B is created and launched, on top of the already exists one, so I have 2 main activities in application B task.

The main activity has NO special attributes set in the manifest, so its `launchMode` attribute is automatically set as standard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the launch mode of the main activity in Application B to SingleTask or SingleInstance in Application B's AndroidManifest.xml?

See [Launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is already open onNewIntent override method will be called. Implement the method based on your requirement.My requirement was to maintain only one activity task. so i'm starting new task and finishing the old task. Implement this in activity B

```
 @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
 };
```